# Affine Cremona group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let us consider affine Cremona group $GA_{n}$ ($n\gt 1$).

Question: do exist finite-dimensional representation of $GA_{n}$ ?

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Silly comment: I assume you are asking about faithful representations. Every group has the trivial one dimensional representation. (I don't have any more substantive comments, but I expect someone will.)

Comment: Yes, I would like to know about existence of finite-dimensional (of dimension bigger then 1) irreducible representation.

Answer (score 10):

I mentioned [here](http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/cremona.pdf) (esp. Remark 5.3) that $GA_2$ has no faithful linear representation (finite-dimensional, over any field), but the proof can easily be modified to show that any linear representation of the kernel $SGA_2$ of the determinant of the Jacobian has no nontrivial linear representation (and thus any linear representation of $GA_2$ has an abelian image).

To summarize the proof: by the (elementary) computation done in the above link, if $M(x,y)=(x,x+y)$, then for every
$n$ there exists a nilpotent subgroup $N$ of $SGA_2$ such that $M$ belongs to the $n$-th term of the descending central series of $N$. Nilpotency lengths of nilpotent subgroups in a given dimension are bounded. It easily follows that $M$ is killed by every linear representation of $SGA_2$. Also the normal subgroup generated by $M$ contains the linear, and thus the affine transformations of the plane and using generation of $GA_2$ by affine and elementary transformations it's easy to conclude. (I might include this further remark since the paper is not yet published.)

For $n\ge 3$ this still proves that every linear representation of $GA_n$ kills the affine transformations with determinant one, but I don't know if it's enough to conclude that all linear representations have an abelian image.

Comment: Yes it would be interesting to add this nice remark.

Answer (score 3):

There is one obvious representation which takes an automorphism of $\mathbb A^n$ to the determinant of its Jacobian. Let $G_n$ be its kernel. It carries a natural structure of  infinite-dimensional algebraic group. Shafarevich proved that $G_n$ is simple as an algebraic group  in this [paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5726/18/1/A10/pdf/IZV_18_1_A10.pdf). Perhaps this suffices to answer your question but I am not sure.

> **Edit.**  According to Jérémy's comment below the proof of Shafarevich
>   does not work. Apparently, the
>   simplicity of $G_n$ as
>   an algebraic group is an open problem
>   for $n \ge 3$.

However it is  known that $G_2$, as an abstract group, is not simple. This was proved by Danilov in this other [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=357626). According to [Furter and Lamy](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0910/0910.1616v2.pdf), Danilov shows that the normal subgroup generated by $(ea)^{13}$, where $a = (y,−x)$ and $e = (x,y+ 3x^5 − 5x^4)$, is a strict subgroup of $G_2$. For a more general statement see the  paper By Furter and Lamy.

It is also known that planar Cremona group ${\mathrm{Bir}}(\mathbb P^2)$ is not simple. This was proved recently by [Cantat and Lamy](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0895).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I also would like to put again my question and do it more precisely: Do exist finite-dimensional (of dimension bigger then 1) irreducible representation of G_{n} ? 



Comment: Thanks for the interesting information about non-simplicity of 
Bir(P^{2})!

Comment: Pay attention, the proof of Shafarevich is known to be completely false. The fact that $G_2$ is simple as an infinite-dimensional algebraic group is not so hard to find, but it is still open if $G_n$ is simple or not, as an infinite-dimensional algebraic group, for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: In fact, the case of $G_2$ is already open...